# Div com Onclick mas não em seus elementos jquery

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma div e nela alguns elemtos, esta div precisa ser clicavel e que seu clique fará uma ação, mas, seus elementos que alguns são buttons também tem ações próprias,o que ocorre é que quando clico nos elementos, é chamado a função do elemento mas também chamado a função da div.

DIV exemplo:

```
    <div class="detalhes" id="2">
        teste

            <button class="Remove" remove_item="a" >
                texto
            </button>
    </div>

    <div class="detalhes" id="3">
        teste

            <button class="Remove" remove_item="a" >
                texto
            </button>
    </div>
```

DIV função:

```
    $(".detalhes").click(function()
    {
        var reg = $(this).attr("id");

    });
```

Elemento:

```
        $('body').on("click", ".Remove", function()
        {
            var Remove_item     = $(this).attr("Remove_item");
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa usar `.stopPropagation()` no elemento pai do botão, no caso o `.detalhes`. Logo, basta alterar o seletor do click no `.Remove` para `.detalhes` em vez de `body`, e pegar o evento colocando um parâmetro na função:

```
$('.detalhes').on("click", ".Remove", function(evt){
  evt.stopPropagation();
  var Remove_item     = $(this).attr("Remove_item");
});
```

O `.stopPropagation()` evita o *bubbling*, que é quando um evento de um elemento filho dispara também eventos no elemento pai.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(".detalhes").click(function(){
  var reg = $(this).attr("id");
  console.log(reg);

});

$('.detalhes').on("click", ".Remove", function(evt){
  evt.stopPropagation();
  var Remove_item     = $(this).attr("Remove_item");
  console.log(Remove_item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="detalhes" id="2">
   teste
   <button class="Remove" remove_item="a" >
      texto
   </button>
</div>

<div class="detalhes" id="3">
   teste
   <button class="Remove" remove_item="b" >
   texto
   </button>
</div>
```